# SharePoint ReplaceContent="TRUE"

Tags: module, deploy

I am trying to deploy pages to a pages library for the second time by activating a feature. The module has the attribute: ReplaceContent="TRUE".

When I deactivate the feature, everything goes fine. When I activate the feature, I receive an error that the pages are checked out to another user (which is my account, the same account am doing the activate process with), and I can't deploy the pages.

Do I need to have the pages checked in? even if am the same user who has them checked out?

Do I need to delete the page before activating the feature to deploy the new page?

Also if someone can tell me the difference between IgnoreIfAlreadyExists and ReplaceContent .

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to delete the page.You just need to check in the page even if it is same account.

`ReplaceContent` allows you to overwrite the `ghostable` file.This is nw

`IgnoreIfAlreadyExists=true`
SharePoint doesn’t freak out if the file already existed in the library but it never allowed us to replace the file.

Please find link below.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/how24/2013/06/14/overwriting-ghostable-files-in-sharepoint-2013-libraries-using-feature-elements-no-code/

Comment: Thanks Akshay, the article says that if the user trying to activate the feature is the same user who has the document checked out to, it should be OK: "One thing to be careful with though, if the document or file you are trying to replace is checked out by a different user, other than the user you are using to activate the feature, the feature activation will fail with the following error:"  In my case, it's giving an error that the file is checked out by another usr.

Comment: Any idea......?